# If we are wanting to resign an iPhone app with a different certificate, do we have to change the bundle id?

Tags: iphone, codesign

We have an iPhone app that needs to be resigned by another company for their Enterprise program.

Is the only required step to resign using their certificate?  It seems like a new provisioning profile would have to be created with a unique bundle id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need a distribution profile with that certificate and a bundle ID matching the app ID on that profile.

Comment: Will the app install correctly if we just resign using their certificate?  It would be using our bundle id, but I'm not sure that's an issue?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you have to have everything match.  You could just try it and see.

Comment: Ok, that worked.  However, the trick is the Entitlements.plist/dist.plist must batch the bundle id after using codesign.  It was a gotcha for me as the app installs fine, but the keychain is messed up between loads.

Comment: If you want to avoid keychain mess you might want to try www.aironapp.com. It does the recodesigning on the fly and provides OTA installation links.